# Hashing user ID's and creating a temp table

Tags: sql, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to pull sample data, but need to mask/hash `userid`'s.  I need to build a temp table first because I'm working in Zeppelin and the output is truncated, so I'm building a temp table so I can query the data from a 3rd party tool (Razor SQL).

Here's what I'm using to mask/hash the `userid`:

```
CREATE TABLE user.temp_userdata_hashed AS
SELECT *, md5(concat(userid, 'useridGUI')) as userid
FROM medicaldata
```

This works without CREATE TABLE, but when I include CREATE TABLE I get this error:

> ```
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the table definition of `user`.`temp_userdata_hashed`: `userid`;
> ```

Rather than listing out every single column in this table (I need them all), is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, my advice would be to just explicitly state the columns you need. However, if you absolutely want to use *, There's really only one workaround. Both have you creating the table as specified in your query, with the exception of using a non-duplicate column name for the userid hash, like in the example below.

```
CREATE TABLE user.temp_userdata_hashed AS
SELECT *, md5(concat(userid, 'useridGUI')) as useridhash
FROM medicaldata
```

Once you've created the temp table you can then use an ALTER TABLE command to drop the original userid column and then rename the useridhash to userid. Then you can keep using * when you query the temp table with SELECT.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing, but was wondering if there was another way around this.